# r producing multiple violin plots with one graphic device

Tags: r, plot

I have a data frame that looks like that:

```
bin_with_regard_to_strand CLONE3
 31                      0.14750872 
 33                      0.52735917
 28                      0.48559060
 .                            .
 .                            .
```

I want to use this data frame to generate violin plots in such a way that all of the values in `CLONE3` corresponding to a given value of  `bin_with_regard_to_strand` will generate one plot.
Further, I want all of the plots to appear in the same graphic device (I'm using R-studio, and I want all of the plots to appear in one plot window).
Theoretically I could do this with:

```
vioplot(df$CLONE3[which(df$bin_with_regard_to_strand==1)], 
  df$CLONE3[which(df$bin_with_regard_to_strand==2)]...)
```

but since `bin_with_regard_to_strand` has 60 different values, this seems a bit ridiculous.
I tried using `tapply`:

```
tapply(df$CLONE3, df$bin_with_regard_to_strand,vioplot)
```

But that would open 60 different windows (one for each plot).
Or, if I used the `add` parameter:

```
 tapply(df$CLONE3, df$bin_with_regard_to_strand,vioplot(add=TRUE))
```

generated a single plot with the data from all values `bin_with_regard_to_strand` (seperated by lines).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try `ggplot2`  here are some examples http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_violin.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `par(mfrow=c(rows, columns))` (see `?par` for details).

(see also `?layout` for complexer arrangements)

```
d <- lapply(1:6, function(x)runif(100)) # generate some example data

library("vioplot")

par(mfrow=c(3, 2)) # use a 3x2 (rows x columns) layout

lapply(d, vioplot) # call plot for each list element

par(mfrow=c(1, 1)) # reset layout
```

[image: vioplots]

Comment: Thanks! that did exactly waht I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to `mfrow`, is to use  `layout`. It is very handy to organize your plots. You just create a matrix with plots index. Here what you can do. It seems that 60 boxplots is a huge number. Maybe you should organize them in 2 pages.

[image]

The code below in function of N (number of plots)

```
library(vioplot)
N <- 60
par(mar=rep(2,4))  
layout(matrix(c(1:N),
              nrow=10,byrow=T))
dat <- data.frame(bin_with_regard_to_strand=gl(N,10),CLONE3=rnorm(10*N))
with(dat , 
     tapply(CLONE3,bin_with_regard_to_strand ,vioplot))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but though I would put out a different solution for getting vioplot to make multiple violin plots on the same graph (i.e. same axes), rather than on different graphics objects like the above answers.

Basically use `do.call` to apply `vioplot` to a list of data. Ultimately, vioplot is not very well written (can't even set the title, axis names, etc.). I usually prefer base R, but this is a case where ggplot2 options is probably the way to go.

```
x<-rnorm(1000)
fac<-rep(c(1:10),each=100)
listOfData<-tapply(x,fac,function(x){x},simplify=FALSE)
names(listOfData)[[1]]<-"x" #because vioplot requires a 'x' argument
do.call(vioplot,listOfData)
```

[resultingImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gDFx.png)